# Dynamically create scroll view in Android using Activity

Tags: android, dynamic, scrollview, tablelayout

We have created a table dynamically in our main activity, however we need to make the table scrollable.  In XMLs I would just put the table layout inside a Scroll layout.  Is there a way to do this dynamically through the activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can put your entire layout inside of a ScrollView programmatically like this:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
scrollView.addView(view);
setContentView(scrollView);
```

Comment: That works great.  We were very close to getting it but needed the addView method.  Thanks!